# Access a web page from Node script on desktop

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I know that this could be a very stupid question, but, since I'm totally new to Javascript, I'm not sure about how to do this. I want to write a script and run it through `node` on my laptop, and, in this script, I want to interact with a web page in order to use functions like `document.getElementById` and stuff like that.

In Python one could do this by using something like `Beautiful Soup` or `requests`, but how do you do this in Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a crawler using cheerio and request-promise as follows:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio

```
let request = require('request-promise');
let cheerio = require('cheerio');

request = request.defaults({
    transform: function (body) {
        return cheerio.load(body);
    }
});

// ... omitted

request({uri: 'http://example.org'})
    .then($ => {
        const element = $('.element-with-class');
    });
```

Comment: And if you want to get an element by it's ID, you do like this: `const element = $('#id-of-wanted-element');`